# Can I submit app to App Store if I install OS X Yosemite and XCode 6 GM?

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

Currently I have Mountain Lion OSX.

I want to download the XCode 6 GM.  I'm thinking to upgrade the my Mini Mac (late 2009, 8GB) to Yosemite preview instead of Mavericks.

If I install Yosemite preview and XCode 6 GM, can I submit app to the App Store? Or only with Mavericks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description says it.

Xcode 6 GM seed

> Xcode 6 GM seed, including the new Swift programming language, is free
>   for Registered Apple Developers. Sign in with your Apple ID to
>   download. **Xcode 6 GM seed runs on OS X Mavericks.**

Xcode 6.1 beta for OS X Yosemite

> This pre-release version of the Xcode 6.1 developer tools is required
>   when developing for OS X Yosemite, and includes the Swift programming
>   language. **Xcode 6.1 beta runs on OS X Mavericks and OS X Yosemite
>   Developer Preview.**

Comment: check this :
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action
it's not strange they put Yosomite develoer preview 7 and xcode 6 GM "together" on same page, like you can download and use them all together ?

Comment: It doesn't appear for me on that page, it does when i select xcode versions, and thats where you can see the description. I haven't personally tried and it can probably be run but might require to change something.